# How to access custom namespaced (react-)JSS theme from components?

Tags: reactjs, themes, jss

I'm creating a react/redux app, and want to utilize JSS theming to style my app/components. I'm also using other libraries that use JSS theming, e.g. Material UI, thus I need to create a namespaced theme as described in  http://cssinjs.org/react-jss?v=v8.1.0#theming to avoid conflicts with other themes.

Does this mean that I have to import my namespaced theme in *every* component I want to style with that theme, and pass it to `injectSheet`? I.e:

```
import React from 'react
import injectSheet, {ThemeProvider} from 'react-jss

// import my custom namespaced theming object...
import theming from '../path/to/my/custom/theming'

const styles = theme => ({
  container: {
    background: theme.background,
  }
})

const Demo = () => (
    <div className={props.classes.container}>
      //...
    </div>
)

// injectSheet with my custom namespaced theming object..
export default injectSheet(styles, {theming})(Demo)
```

This feels very cumbersome. Is it another way that one should do this? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your injectSheet function in a central place and always pass the theming there.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. Are you suggesting to create a HOC `injectSheetWithCustomTheming(styles)` which returns `injectSheet(styles, {theming})` ? Then I would need to import and use this instead of react-jss' `injectSheet`?